# Export variable defined by an async function - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to store the result of a fetch in a const LANGUAGE. But it doesn't work, the problem is the async function. LANGUAGE is equal to :

```
{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
```

While it should contain data accessible [there](https://harmony-project.xyz/app/get-language.php).
My code is :

```js
async function get_language() {
    const response = await fetch("https://harmony-project.xyz/app/get-language.php");
    return await response.json();
}
export const LANGUAGE = get_language();
console.log(LANGUAGE);
```

Could anyone tell me how should I do to store the result ?

Comment: An async function returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}` this means you have an unresolved promise. This is because when you declare a function with the async keyword that function returns a promise.  Try this implemenation.

```
var url = "https://harmony-project.xyz/app/get-language.php";
      async function get_language() {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return await response.json();
      }

      get_language().then((languages) => {
        console.log(languages);
      });
```